# How to remove/delete an artefact via Maven in a remote Nexus repo?

Tags: maven-3, nexus

How can I use maven in an 'undeploy' fashion to remove an artefact deployed to the nexus staging repo?

I currently execute the a command like below for deployment:

```
deploy:deploy-file -Durl=${bamboo.ArtefactsNexusUrl} -DrepositoryId=${bamboo.nexusRepoId} -DgroupId=${bamboo.GroupId} -DartifactId=${bamboo.ArtefactName} -Dversion=${bamboo.inject.VERSION} -Dfile=${bamboo.ArtefactName}-${bamboo.inject.VERSION}.${bamboo.ArtefactExtension} -Dpackaging=${bamboo.ArtefactExtension}
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your use case? I think it's "against maven philosophy" to undeploy something.

Comment: A staging repository will usually be created by a `mvn deploy` which deployes all artifacts. But you seemed to be installing an artifact manually in your staging repository which i would prevent. Why not deploying such an artifact in a separate repository which is called `3rd parts` and leave those versions untouched...

Comment: Apologies for the delay @Denise. The idea is to handle the the `approval` via an automated approach. Which means a 'disapproval' should drop the artifact from the repo. We looked at staging repositories and I was told that each time an artifact is uploaded the `base_url` (yum repo) changes which was not fit for purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the whole staging repository with the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin or via the Nexus user interface. Check out the [documentation in the book.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html)